# Automatically add the date a row was last changed/updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Here I have 3 columns, and I need to the formula/function which will add the date of edit when status is "Sold". For example, if "Orange 1 " has status "Sold " place the date of change in there. I need to[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlUi4.png) apply this formula to all cells

Comment: I recommend that you read the Help Center article "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)". I also recommend that you Edit your question to improve the quality and better help SO community provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Index As Integer: Index = 2
    
    Do Until Range("B" & Index).Value = ""
        If Range("B" & Index).Value = "Sold" Then
             Dim dDate As Date: dDate = Date
        
            Range("C" & Index).Value = dDate
        End If
        Index = Index + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == 'Sold') {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```